# How to make threads work at the same time to achieve my goal?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to make a school timetable. I have a 2D array for the days of the week(5) and how many classes there are a day(6).

```
string[,] timeTable = new string[5,6];
```

I've created a separate class for the subject with the needed variables.

```
internal class Subjects
    {
        public string subjectName { get; set; } = default!;
        public string teacherName { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool subjectAssigned { get; set; }
        public int classesCount { get; set; }
    }
```

I've created a collection of the subjects with a List. I'm posting only 2 subjects here for the minimal reproductive example but I have 11 and the classesCount of all of them adds up to 30. (5 days of the week * 6 classes a day = 30).

```
List<Subjects> _subjects = new()
{
    new Subjects
    {
        subjectName = "Math",
        teacherName = "John Stones",
        subjectAssigned = false,
        classesCount = 4
    },

    new Subjects
    {
        subjectName = "Literature",
        teacherName = "Shakespeare",
        subjectAssigned = false,
        classesCount = 2
    }
};
```

Then I turn the list to array to iterate it.

```
Subjects[] arraySubjects = _subjects.ToArray<Subjects>();
```

After that, I implement my logic of how the array should be filled with the name of the subjects in a function.

```
void AssignSubject(string subjectName)
{
    bool shouldBreak = false;
    int sameSubjectCount = 0;

    foreach (Subjects _subject in arraySubjects)
    {
        if (subjectName == _subject.subjectName) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                sameSubjectCount = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
                {
                    if (timeTable[i, j] == null)
                    {
                        timeTable[i, j] = _subject.subjectName;
                        shouldBreak = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (timeTable[i, j] == _subject.subjectName)
                    {
                        sameSubjectCount++;

                        if (sameSubjectCount == 2)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shouldBreak == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function with a count for the assigned subject in that day and a boolean to know if it's needed to **break;** the for loop. Then for every subject in the subjectArray I check if the name given as a parameter to the function is the same as the name that we are currently on in the array. With 2 for loops I iterate through the 2D array, checking every value. If a value is null, then I assign a value and break the loop. If there isn't a null value, I check if the value is the same as the subject, in which case I increment the int for the number of classes. If it reaches 2 for the day, then I break the for loop and make the shouldBreak value through, so I can break the loop for the days as well.

Here is an example of the threads:

```
var mathsThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(arraySubjects[0].teacherName + " is choosing slots for the subject " + arraySubjects[0].subjectName);

    while (arraySubjects[0].subjectAssigned != true)
    {
        AssignSubject(arraySubjects[0].subjectName);

        arraySubjects[0].classesCount--;

        if (arraySubjects[0].classesCount == 0)
        {
            arraySubjects[0].subjectAssigned = true;
            Console.WriteLine(arraySubjects[0].teacherName + " chose a slot.");
        }
    }
});
```

I've got 11 similar blocks of code for the threads. The only difference is the name(every subject got it's name in there instead of maths) and the numbers in **subjectArray[0]**(number changes based on the number of the subject in the List). The thread call the function for assigning inside a while loop, that works until the subject has assigned all of it's classes.

I start the threads as follows:

```
mathsThread.Start();
mathsThread.Join();
```

And then I show the result like this:

```
void printArray()
{
    string text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                text = "Monday:";
                break;
            case 1:
                text = "Tuesday:";
                break;
            case 2:
                text = "Wednesday:";
                break;
            case 3:
                text = "Thursday:";
                break;
            case 4:
                text = "Friday:";
                break;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            text += " " + timeTable[i, j] + "|";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}

printArray();
```

And here is the result:

```
Monday: Maths| Maths| Physics| Physics| Chemistry| Chemistry|
Tuesday: Maths| Maths| Physics| Chemistry| Biology| Biology|
Wednesday: Biology| English| English| Literature| Literature| PE|
Thursday: English| Literature| Literature| PE| Music| Art|
Friday: Geography| Geography| History| History| French| French|
```

This works fine but I don't like how all the subjects have 2 classes one after the other and I know that is because of the **.Join** which doesn't allow another thread to start before the current one is done. I've removed it and it works good at the start and there is the divercity I want in the days, but some subjects aren't assigned and I can't seem to figure out why. First, I though it was because for friday there would sometimes be left 3 classes of the same subject, which isn't allowed with my code, so I thought it's cuz of that, but sometimes the subject that isn't assigned isn't even on the day. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what to do to fix it? This is an example of the result I get if I remove the **.Join**

```
Monday: Physics| Physics| Maths| Maths| Chemistry| Chemistry|
Tuesday: Physics| Maths| Chemistry| Biology| Biology| English|
Wednesday: Biology| English| English| Literature| Literature| PE|
Thursday: Literature| Literature| PE| Music| Art| Geography|
Friday: Geography| History| History| French| French| |
```

There is 1 missing Math class, which I don't understand why it doesn't go to the last slot?

Comment: This is really not a good fit for using multiple threads. Why are you doing that? If you call start and join in sequence, you could as well execute that code on the same thread. If you just leave out the join, you'll have collisions because the shared resource is accessed not thread safe.

Comment: @Fildor How to make it thread safe?

Comment: The easiest way is to [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) the resource while accessing it. Which of course takes away some of the concurrency, making threads wait for the resource. But the question still stands: why use threads in the first place?

Comment: Btw: you can perfectly fine iterate a List<T>.  No need to make it an array just for the sake of iterating it.

Comment: @Fildor it's an assignment from uni. The subject we are studying is about parallel programming, but I missed a lot of the course cuz of personal issues and couldn't really catch up in time, so now I'm trynna make the project before I get a bad grade and will fill the gaps in knowledge afterwards.

Comment: Well, in that case, SO has specific rules that apply for "homework"-ish questions. Make sure to look them up. But to your problem: I figure you are supposed to simulate multiple teachers trying to reserve slots for their courses?

Comment: @Fildor yes, excactly

Comment: Ok... then apart from locking access to the shared resource, when simulating something like that, you will usually also introduce some random jitter. That means: the "teachers" do not reserve slots as fast as they can. Instead, they would start at slightly different times, then maybe "think" about their second pick for a randomly chosen time,  etc.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions make sure to read this, too.